# Unit testing Kohana ORM Model throw Exception error

Tags: orm, phpunit, kohana

When I try to test my Kohana(3.3.0) ORM Model with PHPUnit, it throw this exception below.

```
Website_MetadataTest::testCountMetadata
ErrorException: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

/home/liva/Workspace/htdocs/Revoyance-Local/modules/orm/cla sses/Kohana/ORM.php:1014
/home/liva/Workspace/htdocs/Revoyance-Local/modules/orm/classes/Kohana/ORM.php:1041
/home/liva/Workspace/htdocs/Revoyance-Local/modules/orm/classes/Kohana/ORM.php:1001
/home/liva/Workspace/htdocs/Revoyance-Local/tests/classes/Website/MetadataTest.php:21
```

I inspect all this files and it seems that ORM.php is unable to load table columns list from database.

Have you guys ever had this error ? did you find any solution. I suspect that I have missed some configuration somewhere but I don't know where !

My test class looks like this

```
require DOCROOT . 'tests/classes/DatabaseTestCase.php';

class Website_MetadataTest extends DatabaseTestCase
{
protected $metadata;

    public function getDataSet()
    {
        return $this->createXMLDataSet(DOCROOT.'tests/_data/website-metadata.xml');
    }

public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->metadata = ORM::factory('Website_Metadata')->where('website_id', '=', 1)->find_all();
    }

    public function testCountMetadata()
    {
        $this->assertCount(4, $this->metadata);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that PHPUnit is using PDO for database access. Kohana's PDO driver does not implement `list_columns` because PDO does not have native support for getting the table description. Instead, it throws an exception.

When using PDO, the workaround is to list all columns in the Model class, like this:

```
class Model_Website_Metadata extends ORM
{
    protected $_table_name = 'website_meta';
    protected $_primary_key = 'website_metadata_id';

    protected $_table_columns = array(
        'website_metadata_id' => NULL,
        'website_id' => NULL,
        'meta_page_id' => NULL,
        'title' => NULL,
        'description' => NULL,
        'logo' => NULL,
        'header' => NULL,
        'header2' => NULL,
        'pagination' => NULL
    ); 
}
```